# Using a gui-overlay plugin to choose GAZEBO_MASTER_URI for a gzclient

Tags: gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

i have several gzserver running in docker containers. Im mapping the container-ports from 11345 to localhost:xxxx (e.g. 1000 < xxxx < 1100).

I would like to write an gui plugin which opens an dialog window, allowing to choose one of the ports in my range as GAZEBO_MASTER_URI for my running gzclient.

Anyone know if this is possible? Im actually browsing the sourcecode of the gazebo gui (https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/bcbea7608b1ad88067ef652e8e7a4b93ec1001cf/gazebo/gui/?at=default) but i could need some hints from someone more experienced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18297/using-a-gui-overlay-plugin-to-choose-gazebo_master_uri-for-a-gzclient./) by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 350 on 2018-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think that once the GUI plugin has been loaded, it is too late to change the master URI because the transport system has already been setup.

One alternative I can think of, but adds complexity, would be to have custom GUI program (doesn't even need to link against Gazebo) where you can choose a port and that program launches `gzclient` with the appropriate port.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) on 2018-01-17**:
I was expecting that answer. Well just wrote a simple python script to spawn gzclients with different master URIs. This will be ok. Thanks for replying!